# In C# , How should I change the method syntax when I want to move it from my controller to a repository file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, repository

I am trying to create a method in a repository file that will call things from my query and model files, I tried to solve the errors by using directive, it got rid of most of the errors but I still have two persistent ones. The method was previously in my controller, and since I want to move it to my repo folder, I am guessing the syntax will change somewhat. I am new to C# and I am not sure how to approach this.

**Error 1** 
'GetSportsView': I get an error saying "not all code paths return a value"

**Error 2**
'QueryView>' :
I get "object does not contain a definition for 'QueryView' and no accessible extension method(are you missing a directive or assembly reference)"

Please see the code below

```
 public class SportsRepository : ISportsRepository
    {
        private readonly IHttpConnectionManager httpConnectionManager;
        private readonly string sportsGrandViewUrl;
        private readonly Guid playerId;
        private SearchCriteria searchCriteria;
        private object sportsGameRepository;

         public SportsRepository(taDomainCommunicationSettings taDomainCommunicationSettings, IHttpConnectionManager httpConnectionManager)
        {
            this.sportsGrandViewUrl = taDomainCommunicationSettings.SportsGrandViewUrl;
            this.httpConnectionManager = httpConnectionManager;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSportsView(Guid playerId, [FromQuery]SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
        {
            var query = new GetSportsTransactionsQuery(playerId, searchCriteria);
            var result = await this.sportsGameRepository.QueryView<IEnumerable<SportsTransactionModel>>(query);
        }

        public Task<T> QueryView<T>(IAPIQuery qry)
        {
            return this.httpConnectionManager.PostInQueryWrapperAsync<T>(this.sportsGrandViewUrl, qry);
        }
    }
}
```

How should I approach the syntax style to make it work the same way it worked in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have mixed up controller's code with repository's. Like FromQuery is used with request's query parameters, it should not be used here in repository.

When I first began with web development using repository pattern, this article helped me lot : https://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/.

Basically your controller should call service, and your service will interact with your repository. This helps in keeping both code and logic modularized.